# github access only through VPN

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm looking at github as a source control repository. I've never used it and don't know much about it other than it has a solid reputation.

My question is this: is it possible to limit the access to a github account only to IP addresses coming from a certain VPN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

However, there is a [self-hosted version](https://enterprise.github.com/).